# Obtain numbers from 0 to 9 with the digits of 2022 in that order

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

The title says (nearly) all. Write the digits $2$ $0$ $2$ $2$ in that order and apply mathematical operators to obtain all values from 0 to 9. What's allowed:

- The four basic operators, $+ - * /$
- Parenthesis to force the order of operations
- Power (like $2^0$)
- Factorial (like $2!$)
- Concatenation (like $202$)
- Square root ($\sqrt {}$)
- Digital point (with or without leading 0, like $2.02$ or $.2$)
- Periodic numbers (like $.\overline{2}$)

I did not need to use truncation.

Comment: You are about two months early.

Comment: @Bass: I am letting people prepare in advance for puzzles for New Year's Eve

Comment: Future Shock Syndrome...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> 0: 2*0*22
>
> 1: 2*0+(2/2)
>
> 2: 2+0+2-2
>
> 3: 2+0+(2/2)
>
> 4: 2*0+2+2
>
> 5: 2^0+2+2
>
> 6: 2+0+2+2
>
> 7: 2+0!+2+2
>
> 8: (2+0)*2*2
>
> 9: (2^0+2)^2
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Since

> 2x0=0, we can add zero to 2-2=0, 2/2=1, sqrt(2x2)=2, sqrt(2/.2rec)=3, 2x2=4, 2/.2rec=9 to get 0,1,2,3,4,9.

Since

> 2-0!=1 and 2-0=2, we can add 1 or 2 instead of 0, or (-2+0+ etc.) subtract instead of adding, getting 5,6 as 1+4,2+4 and 8,7 as 9-1,9-2.

And we're done.

Answer (score 6):

Alternate solutions.  Mostly.

> $0 = 2 \times 0 \times 2 \times 2$
>   $1 = 2 + 0 - 2/2$
>   $2 = 2 + 0 \times 2/2$
>   $3 = 2 + 0 + 2 / 2$
>   $4 = 2 \times 0 + 2 \times 2$
>   $5 = 20/2/2$
>   $6 = 2 + 0 + 2 + 2$
>   $7 = 2/0.\overline{2} - 2$
>   $8 = 20/2 - 2$
>   $9 = (20 - 2)/2$

Comment: I completely missed the solution for 9... My own solution was $ 20/2.\overline{2}$

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but:

> $2×0+2-2=0$ 
>     $2×0+2/2=1$ 
>     $2+0+2-2=2$ 
>     $2+0+2/2=3$ 
>     $2×0+2+2=4$ 
>     $2^0+2+2=5$ 
>     $2+0+2+2=6$ 
>     $-2+0+2/.\overline{2}=7$
>     $2×(0+2+2)=8$ 
>     $2×0+2/.\overline{2}=9$

Comment: Very simple and elegant, esp. 7 and 9. If we assign points for using the more advanced, this would win.  Btw. in 7 you used unary minus which the rules didn't spell out was allowed.